# Register Custom ModelBinder in Asp.NET Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

Using .NET Framework MVC, one would register a custom model binder like so:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyModel), new MyModelBinder());
```

Then any controller action that had a parameter of type `MyModel` would automatically use `MyModelBinder` to bind its value.

```
public ActionResult Test(MyModel o){
   // dunski!
   ...
}
```

It seems like in .NET Core MVC, one must specify the use of `MyModelBinder` each time rather than registering it once only - or am I mistaken?

```
public IActionResult Test([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MyModelBinder))] MyModel o){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Decorating the `type` that is being model-bound with the `[ModelBinder]` attribute will cause any parameter of the same type (in your controller actions) to be automatically bound using the model binder specified in the `[ModelBinder]` attribute.

Example:

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MyModelBinder))]
public class MyModel{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Age{ get; set; }
}

public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // whatever model binding you need to do
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(new MyModel());

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

More on this at [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-model-binder-sample)